# Regarding the way to setup Activation and BatchNormalization in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I once saw the convolutional layers are defined as follows in `Keras`

```
x = Convolution2D(128, kernel, kernel, border_mode='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Convolution2D(128, kernel, kernel, border_mode='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
```

It seems to me that `Activation` can be also setup in `Convolution2D` as well. What are the reasons to setup `Activation` in an independent layer as the above? Moreover, between `Convolution2D` and `Activation`, there is `BatchNormalization`, can we move `BatchNormalization` after `Activation`? Will there be any difference then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a settled matter. Most people have batch normalization before the activation function. However, in practice some have found that having batch normalization after the activation function also works, and as far as I know there is no consensus on what's better. I suggest you try both on your particular problem and data. Don't expect any major differences however.